# Overriding with changed visibility

Tags: java

In the following program, if msg() in A is declared as public, b.display() in main() calls B's version of msg(). But, if msg() in A is declared as private, b.display() in main() calls A's version of msg(). Could you please tell me why this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

```
class A {
    private String msg() {
        return "Message from class A";
    }

    void display() {
        System.out.println(msg());
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public String msg() {
        return "Message from class B's msg()";
    }
}

class Tests {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        B b = new B();

        // private version of msg defined in A will be called
        // if msg is defined as public in A, the version of msg defined in B is called
        b.display();

        // the version defined in B is called
        System.out.println(b.msg());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you logan for the reference.

So at bottomline, a private method of a class cannot be overridden in a subclass because the subclass has no idea about the private method of the superclass. Instead a new method is created in the subclass. In the case of this program, msg() defined in B is entirely different from msg() defined in A. There is no overriding in this case.

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Because the method of A

```
private String msg() {
        return "Message from class A";
    }
```

is private. To override it, it has to be public and on B there should be the `@Override` notation like this

```
class B extends A {
    @Override
    public String msg() {
        return "Message from class B's msg()";
    }
}
```

Comment: There does not have to be an `@Override` annotation, but including one ensures that the method actually overrides the one in its superclass at compile-time.

Comment: thanks, i was actually not aware of that, as Intellij always does that for me ;)

Comment: No problem! Just remember that method overriding was available when Java was first released. Annotations were not added until Java 5.

Answer (score 1):

This is, in short, because you cannot override a private method - Java doesn't allow it.

You can think of all private methods as effectively being marked with the `final` modifier.

If you want to ensure a method has definitely overridden another one, use the @Override annotation. This will let you know if it hasn't, by throwing an error at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Because in java , extended class only have possibility upconversion modifier, not else.For expamle in your code `Class A have method private msg()` , that extended class make `private msg() to public msg , msg() , and protected msg();`
In your case you create `B b = new B()` and call `b.display()` naturally you call super method (because you have no possibility override private method's) , not extended. And `b.msg()` called from `b` because you overridedd it.